# API update for Sonos version 10.3 API

Tags: sonos

The blog post for Sonos version 10.3 API update posted on July 16, 2019 suggests that the
code at https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/]audioClip namespace will work on the upcoming SYMFONISK table lamp with WiFi speaker and SYMFONISK WiFi bookshelf speaker. When we call the endpoint it does not return the audioclip capability for these speakers and when we try and send an audioclip to it, it returns:

> An error occurred, there were no speakers with the custom sound capability in this group

Expectations is this:

```
"capabilities":["PLAYBACK","CLOUD","AIRPLAY","LINE_IN","AUDIO_CLIP"
```

Get this:

```
"capabilities":["PLAYBACK","CLOUD","AIRPLAY"]
```

Comment: The bookshelf speaker only has 512M of RAM (all other capable players have 1GB), so maybe it can't do audioClip and the docs are wrong? Either that or there's an update due for it that hasn't been released yet. I see the same results as you. (I wouldn't expect to see LINE_IN though).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the sonos speaker firmware 10.4 is now available and this issue is confirmed fixed by this update.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for finding this. The SYMFONISK table lamp with WiFi speaker and SYMFONISK WiFi bookshelf speaker will support commands and events in the AudioClip namespace in the next software release. We updated the documentation. Keep an eye on [the Sonos developer portal blog](https://developer.sonos.com/blog/) for updates.